# Timestamp for Top command leads to mismatch

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following "customized" top command to extract the timestamp info from my "top" command logs:

```
top -b -d 1 -n 60  | awk '{now=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T ");print now $0}' > $(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")_top.log
```

where I run top in batch mode for 60 seconds. However as you can see in my logs, for some "unknown" reason the last process of the snapshot shows the next timestamp. What is the reason and how can I correct it?

```
2019-05-19 03:56:21 top - 03:56:21 up 1 day, 13:24,  1 user,  load average: 1.63, 1.52, 1.56
2019-05-19 03:56:21 Tasks: 113 total,   1 running, 112 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
2019-05-19 03:56:21 %Cpu(s): 53.6 us, 40.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  5.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.4 si,  0.0 st
2019-05-19 03:56:21 KiB Mem :   491172 total,   419048 free,    15592 used,    56532 buff/cache
2019-05-19 03:56:21 KiB Swap:   524284 total,   519188 free,     5096 used.   464680 avail Mem 
2019-05-19 03:56:21 
2019-05-19 03:56:21   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2019-05-19 03:56:21 21404 root      20   0    3192   2040   1720 R 13.5  0.4   0:10.50 top
2019-05-19 03:56:21 22400 root      20   0    3192   2024   1708 S 12.8  0.4   0:02.76 top
2019-05-19 03:56:21   467 root      20   0    3148    992    852 S  4.3  0.2  82:08.48 bash
2019-05-19 03:56:21 22401 root      20   0    3380   1916   1736 S  2.1  0.4   0:00.41 awk
2019-05-19 03:56:21     7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.7  0.0  16:19.62 rcu_preempt
2019-05-19 03:56:21 22403 root      20   0    3380   1912   1736 S  0.7  0.4   0:00.03 awk
2019-05-19 03:56:21     1 root      20   0    2480    180    160 S  0.0  0.0   0:13.28 init
2019-05-19 03:56:21 22619 root      20   0    1988    892    836 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 sleep
2019-05-19 03:56:23 28316 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 kworker/u2:1
2019-05-19 03:56:23 
2019-05-19 03:56:23 top - 03:56:23 up 1 day, 13:24,  1 user,  load average: 1.63, 1.52, 1.56
2019-05-19 03:56:23 Tasks: 113 total,   1 running, 112 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
2019-05-19 03:56:23 %Cpu(s): 53.6 us, 39.9 sy,  0.0 ni,  5.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.4 si,  0.0 st
2019-05-19 03:56:23 KiB Mem :   491172 total,   419048 free,    15592 used,    56532 buff/cache
2019-05-19 03:56:23 KiB Swap:   524284 total,   519188 free,     5096 used.   464680 avail Mem 
2019-05-19 03:56:23 
2019-05-19 03:56:23   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2019-05-19 03:56:23 22400 root      20   0    3192   2024   1708 S 13.9  0.4   0:02.95 top
2019-05-19 03:56:23 21404 root      20   0    3192   2040   1720 R 13.1  0.4   0:10.68 top
2019-05-19 03:56:23   467 root      20   0    3148    992    852 S  4.4  0.2  82:08.54 bash
2019-05-19 03:56:23 21405 root      20   0    3380   1916   1736 S  2.2  0.4   0:01.59 awk
2019-05-19 03:56:23     7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.7  0.0  16:19.63 rcu_preempt
2019-05-19 03:56:23     1 root      20   0    2480    180    160 S  0.0  0.0   0:13.28 init
2019-05-19 03:56:23 22619 root      20   0    1988    892    836 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 sleep
2019-05-19 03:56:24 28316 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 kworker/u2:1
2019-05-19 03:56:24 
2019-05-19 03:56:24 top - 03:56:24 up 1 day, 13:24,  1 user,  load average: 1.58, 1.52, 1.56
2019-05-19 03:56:24 Tasks: 113 total,   1 running, 112 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
2019-05-19 03:56:24 %Cpu(s): 52.6 us, 41.6 sy,  0.0 ni,  4.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.5 si,  0.0 st
2019-05-19 03:56:24 KiB Mem :   491172 total,   418896 free,    15660 used,    56616 buff/cache
2019-05-19 03:56:24 KiB Swap:   524284 total,   519188 free,     5096 used.   464612 avail Mem 
2019-05-19 03:56:24 
2019-05-19 03:56:24   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2019-05-19 03:56:24 21404 root      20   0    3192   2040   1720 R 13.7  0.4   0:10.87 top
2019-05-19 03:56:24 22400 root      20   0    3192   2024   1708 S 12.9  0.4   0:03.13 top
2019-05-19 03:56:24   467 root      20   0    3148    992    852 S  3.6  0.2  82:08.59 bash
2019-05-19 03:56:24 21405 root      20   0    3380   1916   1736 S  2.2  0.4   0:01.62 awk
2019-05-19 03:56:24 22401 root      20   0    3380   1916   1736 S  2.2  0.4   0:00.47 awk
2019-05-19 03:56:24     3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.7  0.0   3:54.70 ksoftirqd/0
2019-05-19 03:56:24     1 root      20   0    2480    180    160 S  0.0  0.0   0:13.28 init
2019-05-19 03:56:24     2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.51 kthreadd
2019-05-19 03:56:24     4 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0
2019-05-19 03:56:24 22619 root      20   0    1988    892    836 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 sleep
2019-05-19 03:56:25 28316 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 kworker/u2:1
2019-05-19 03:56:25 
2019-05-19 03:56:25 top - 03:56:25 up 1 day, 13:24,  1 user,  load average: 1.58, 1.52, 1.56
2019-05-19 03:56:25 Tasks: 113 total,   1 running, 112 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
2019-05-19 03:56:25 %Cpu(s): 59.6 us, 34.6 sy,  0.0 ni,  5.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.0 st
2019-05-19 03:56:25 KiB Mem :   491172 total,   418896 free,    15660 used,    56616 buff/cache
2019-05-19 03:56:25 KiB Swap:   524284 total,   519188 free,     5096 used.   464612 avail Mem 
2019-05-19 03:56:25 
2019-05-19 03:56:25   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2019-05-19 03:56:25 21404 root      20   0    3192   2040   1720 R 13.7  0.4   0:11.06 top
2019-05-19 03:56:25 22400 root      20   0    3192   2024   1708 S 13.7  0.4   0:03.32 top
2019-05-19 03:56:25   467 root      20   0    3148    992    852 S  4.3  0.2  82:08.65 bash
2019-05-19 03:56:25 22401 root      20   0    3380   1916   1736 S  2.2  0.4   0:00.50 awk
2019-05-19 03:56:25     1 root      20   0    2480    180    160 S  0.7  0.0   0:13.29 init
2019-05-19 03:56:26   313 message+  20   0   11780      4      4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 dbus-daemon
2019-05-19 03:56:26   325 root      20   0    6216      4      4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 sshd
2019-05-19 03:56:26   402 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kauditd
2019-05-19 03:56:26   452 root      20   0    3148   1452   1304 S  0.0  0.3   1:07.39 bash
2019-05-19 03:56:26  6488 root      20   0    3148   2004   1892 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.01 sh
2019-05-19 03:56:26 22393 root      20   0    3916   1744   1604 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.00 crond
2019-05-19 03:56:26 22397 root      20   0    3148   1996   1880 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.01 sh
2019-05-19 03:56:26 22619 root      20   0    1988    892    836 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 sleep
2019-05-19 03:56:27 28316 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 kworker/u2:1
```

Comment: Just a second passed, it's not the "next timestamp" - time just flies.

Comment: Why else, because time does _not_ wait

Comment: ha ha. You're right. I was just hoping since the top takes a snapshot of the system state at that "1" second, if this delay could be somehow from the addition of the formatted time

Comment: @shellter: I tried with BEGIN block, but the problem with this is for all the "60" seconds of top command, the time remains the same which is not true :(